# I have installed opencv on ubuntu. I was trying to use function imshow() . it is giving an error

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I have installed the opencv on ubuntu. I was trying to use function imshow(). It is giving an error, please find the below.

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented.
>   Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you
>   are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then
>   re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file
>   /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 545
>
> error Traceback (most recent call last) 
>   in ()
>   ----> 1 cv2.imshow('mask',img)
>
> error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:545: error: (-2) The
>   function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+
>   2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in
>   function cvShowImage

Comment: _If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script_

Comment: I have alredy rerun cmake still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this option in cmake `WITH_GTK=ON`

> OpenCV needs to be compiled with GTK support (WITH_GTK=ON).